# When use tensorflow-gpu cudnn fails during the link time

Tags: python, tensorflow, anaconda

I am trying to use `tensorflow-gpu` on ubuntu. After a series of installing, it fails when I import tensorflow in python3. The error is

```
ImportError: /$MYPATH$/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/../libtensorflow_framework.so: 
symbol cudnnConvolutionBiasActivationForward version libcudnn.so.7 not defined in file libcudnn.so.7 with link time reference
```

My environment is like:

- `cuda` : 9.0.176
- `cudnn` : 7.2
- `tensorflow-gpu` : 1.10

Also, I have add path to cuda in `~/.bashrc` as:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/cuda-9.0/bin${PATH:+:${PATH}}
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda-9.0/lib64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH

export PATH=/usr/local/cuda/bin${PATH:+:${PATH}}
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda/lib64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

I guess the problem is due to wrong cudnn file link but I do not know how to find the exact problem and fix it.

How can I solve this problem? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The reason why cudnn can not find right link is because I am using `anaconda` environment. Instead of install a lot of packages manually, I simply installed `tensorflow-gpu` by using:

```
$conda create --name tf_gpu tensorflow-gpu
$source activate tf_gpu
```

This works! The tutorial is found [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/tensorflow-gpu-installation-made-easy-use-conda-instead-of-pip-52e5249374bc).

But the reason why I can **not** use `pip install tensorflow-gpu` to install correctly is still unknown. **Still** need your help and explaination!